# SQLDF in R - Problems with date format

Tags: sql, r

I am trying apply some transformations in a data.frame using the **sqldf** function in R, but got some weird outputs. (I tried to apply some SQL date transformations in the query, but got no success).

First the data.frame has the following format (all columns are of character class):

[image]

But after filtering the data.frame with 'sqldf':

```
 sqldf("SELECT BP_OR, N_orden_OR, Tipo_ordenOR, N_lineaOR, OLUSER, OLPID, 
      (select Fecha_aprobac from aprob_or 
                 order by Fecha_aprobac desc limit 1) AS LastOfFecha_aprobac, 
                 Estadp_sig, Estado_ultimo
              FROM aprob_or
              GROUP BY BP_OR, N_orden_OR, Tipo_ordenOR, N_lineaOR, OLUSER, OLPID, Estadp_sig, Estado_ultimo
                 (((OLPID)='X43008'))
                ")
```

I got the following format for the column **LastOfFecha_aprobc**

[image]

Those 'P5' is what I don't undestand. I formated the SQL code with some parameters to change the date format, but it persisted.

Do you have a better idea to figure that out?

Comment: Solved the issue!

Comment: If the solution would be useful to others, post it as an answer and accept it. If it was just a typo or mistake, you should close the question.